# How do I create a function that populates a query and returns the query's result in Mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently making a pokémon database in typescript using mongoose to try and learn how mongoose and typescript work, and I'm struggling with a few things.
Currently I'm making a function that receives 2 pokémons that were searched by ID, runs a populate function on the result to get the "species" field, and returns the result for that search.

The "Pokemon" collection has a "Species" field where it references (through an ObjectID) the "Species" collection.
Right now what I want to do is pick this query:

```
Pokemon.findById({
        _id: { $in: [parentsIDs] }
    }).populate<{ species: ISpeciesModel }>('species');
```

and make a function that returns the result of this query.

If the question isn't specific enough I'd be glad to provide more information, I'm not a regular on StackOverflow so I apologize if I've missed anything basic.

Answer (score 0):

A mongoose query can be executed using its `exec()` method, which returns a `Promise` containing the query results.

Query building methods like `populate()` or `findOne()` do not execute the query. The methods build on top of the original query lazily and return a new `Query` instance.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population

```
const results = await Pokemon
  .findById({ _id: { $in: [parentsIDs] }})
  .populate<{ species: ISpeciesModel }>('species')
  .exec();
```

Comment: Then how would I make a function that returns that object? And from what I gathered it'd return a
```(parameter) parents: (Omit<IPokemonModel & {
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
}, "species"> & {
    species: ISpeciesModel;
})[] | null```

object. I don't know quite how to explain but it looks very messy, any way I can organize that? I realize it looks like that because it's effectively fusing both interfaces but it doesn't feel like clean code to me